# Transparent png image is not transparent in browser

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, transparency

Please see this example image below to reference (Illustrator was used here to export). Has anyone noticed that any transparent png files when dropped in a browser (like Chrome or Firefox) do not seem to have transparent backgrounds? I used to drop graphics in Chrome or Firefox as a check before sending a file and I would see a fully transparent background. This example shows the artboard area as white instead. Is there a fix when exporting? Or a setting in the browser?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you certain you don't have some improper export setting, like a matte color?

Comment: Well, I feel positive about this. Please try a png that should have a transparent background like a logo and view it in Chrome or a Firefox browser.

Comment: it works fine here.

Comment: Post the png, rather than a picture of it & we can have a loo .

Comment: Please see the added png above. thanks

Comment: Your PNG is transparent in Chrome here.

Comment: Thank you and for mentioning the "Transparent Standalone Images" Extension.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Chrome, but for Firefox you need an extension called [Transparent Standalone Images](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/transparent-standalone-image/) because in Firefox transparency is normally only visible when the PNG appears on a web page with a background.  It might be better instead to check your images in Photoshop or GIMP, where transparency is displayed using a chequered grid.

Another possible issue is how you are exporting the images in Illustrator. For example, if you are using *Export for Screens*, and you have PNG as the output file format, you need to click on the little cog icon, and change the background colour to transparent.

Example

[image]

Here's an example transparent PNG I created using that method.

[image]

[Here's what it looks like in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAgXC.jpg) with the Transparent Standalone Images extension. Note also that I have no affiliation with the developers of the extension.